# Ненужные файлы в папке Release/Debug C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Написал небольшое приложение. Хочу его внедрить для одного из научных порталов. Компилировал проект, выходящей папкой которого была Release. Сейчас структура папки такова:
[image: структура папки Release]

`database.txt,options,log.xlsx` - файлы/директория, используемые программой
 ну и `spamer.exe`- исполняемый файл само собой.

Скажите, пожалуйста, с остальными файлами что? Они жизненно важны для работы программы? Как почистить папку по максимуму? Т.к. инсталлятор делаться не будет, а конечным вариантом программы должна быть папка с `filename.exe` внутри (эдакая portable версия)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- foo.application — манифест для установки приложений ClickOnce. Если вы им пользуетесь, то оставьте, собственно.
- foo.exe.config — конфигурационный файл, содержащий глобальные настройки. Может содержать настройки версии .NET, строки для подключения к базе, настройки логирования и т. п. Часто можно удалить без последствий, но не рекомендуется.
- foo.exe.manifest — манифест, содержащий совместимость с версиями ОС и оболочки, необходимый уровень прав и т. п. Обычно подходят настройки по умолчанию, но удалять не рекомендуется.
- foo.pdb — файл для отладки. При возникновении исключений обеспечивает подробную информацию о стеке вызовов. Можно оставить, чтобы ошибки от клиента было проще анализировать.
- foo.vshost.* — файлы для хитрого запуска приложения при отладке в Visual Studio. Можно спокойно удалять.

Answer (score 5):

После компиляции, если не требуется дальнейшая отладка, то файлы с раширением .pdb, .vshost.* - можно удалить.
Файлы .config - обычно тоже не нужен, если в него ничего сами не добавляли.

Из всех файлов, которые создаются во время компиляции, в основном, требуются только файлы с расширением exe и dll.
А самое главное - это файлы, с которыми работает ваше приложение -- их можно легко найти после Clean.
Если в Visual Studio в Solution Explorer стать на проект и в контекстном меню выбрать - Clean, то все лишнее удаляется, остаются только ваши файлы. 
Для чего это надо? Например, во время отладки программы в CurrentDirectory программа создает какие-то файлы с очень нужной информацией. Чтобы их не потерять, и не разбираться что-есть-что, делаете Clean -- все лишние файлы удаляются, и можно просто скопировать то, что осталось.

Comment: При выборе "Очистить" удаляется также и *.exe файл с ненужными файлами. При обратной перекомпиляции появляются и *.exe файл, и ненужные файлы :)

Comment: @DmitryShulga после Clean можно найти свои файлы вроде log.xlsx и т.д. -- иногда бывает очень полезно.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял

Comment: @DmitryShulga во время отладки программы бывает в CurrentDirectory программа создает какие-то файлы с очень нужной информацией. и их бывает много. так вот, чтобы их не потерять, и не разбираться что-есть-что, делаешь Clean, все лишние файлы удаляются, и можно просто скопировать то, что осталось.

Comment: *"не нужен, если в него ничего сами не добавляли"* — Не надо добавлять что-то в конфиг вручную, чтобы он вдруг стал нужным. Разные инструменты меняют его самостоятельно, да даже изменение версии .NET в свойствах проекта записывается в этот конфиг.

Comment: @Discord _"Не надо добавлять что-то в конфиг вручную,"_ -- в файл Solution explorer - проект - App.config -- бывает добавляют вручную параметры, которые используются приложением при работе. например, значение 'connectionString' или traceListener. Все что добавляется в App.config оказывается после компиляции в имя_приложения.exe.config